# Solving definite integral from -1 to 1

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Please help me with this. I can't prove the result. Tried integral by parts or notations, nothing working

$$\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}}dx$$

Comment: You write that you cannot prove the result.  What is the result?  Where is your work?

Comment: Let $t=-x$, then$\cdots$.

Comment: I tried to note $e^x+1=t$  then I wrote two simple fractions. I could integrate only one of them. The result is 1/3 ( from my book )

Comment: @Riemann is correct, this is a symmetry problem

Comment: You don't actually have to find an antiderivative. Try substituting $u =-x$ and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you !!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $t=-x$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}}dx
&=\int_{1}^{-1}{\frac{t^2}{e^{-t}+1}}(-dt)\\
&=\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{t^2}{e^{-t}+1}}dt\\
&=\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{x^2e^x}{e^x+1}}dx.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}}dx
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}}dx
+\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{x^2e^x}{e^x+1}}dx\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}x^2dx=\int_{0}^{1}x^2dx\\
&=\frac{1}{3}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Note $\frac{1}{e^x+1}
= \frac12+\frac12\tanh^{-1}\frac x2 $ and the odd function $\tanh^{-1}\frac x2$ does not contribute to the integral over $(-1,1)$. Thus

$$\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}}dx
= \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x^2}2=\frac13
$$